select from a stored comma separated string Model
I have this model VersionKeys that is a comma separated string of keys. I want to select the VersionKeys that Contains that one key. This should return A,b,c,d
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<VersionKeys> VersionKeys = new List<VersionKeys>
            {
                new VersionKeys { Id = 1, keys = "A,b,c,d" },
                new VersionKeys { Id = 2, keys = "d" },
            };
        
        string VersionKey = "c";
        
        var Keys = VersionKeys.Select(s => s.keys).Where(t=> VersionKeys.Select(x => x.keys).Contains(VersionKey)).FirstOrDefault();
        
        
        Console.WriteLine(Keys);
    }
}

public class VersionKeys
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string keys { get; set; }
}

Working sample
https://dotnetfiddle.net/V1GZKf

What's the actual problem? Fixing this is easy - don't work with the strings at all, use a List or HashSet that allows for quick searching. Do those strings come from somewhere else? Are you trying to emulate a database query?

This is almost certainly an XY Problem: you want to search something X and assume you can use LINQ alone for this (Y, the attempted solution). It's possible but also very slow. What's the actual problem ?

Any reason why a string.Contains wouldn't work for you? e.g. overlapping names

You seem to be drastically over-complicating this.  If the goal is to get VersionKeys records where keys contains a given value then that exact statement is semantically expressable in code:
var result = VersionKeys.Where(t => t.keys.Contains(VersionKey)).FirstOrDefault();

In this case result is an instance of VersionKeys and its keys property has the value you want:
Console.WriteLine(result.keys);

The fact that the string is comma-separated values isn't particularly relevant.  All you're doing is checking if a string contains a given substring.
(Having said that... Normalizing the data to separate these values is certainly recommended.)

Or split the string and create a HashSet<string> upon construction. This sounds like an XY Problem and I suspect the data comes from a denormalized table or badly designed API DTO. PS: t.keys.Contains(VersionKey) works even if keys is a HashSet

If I understand correctly, you need to split your values and search as array
var Keys = VersionKeys
    // parse your items into workable models, keep original
    .Select(m => new { m, keys = m.keys.Split(',') })
    .Where(item => item.keys.Contains("c"))
    // select original model
    .Select(item => item.m);
    
// print
Keys.ToList().ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.keys));

Prints a,b,c,d
NOTE: if you have spaces, case sensitivity and other split issues, you might need to add Comparer, Trim, etc
